# Liquibase GenerateChangeLog doesnt include schemaName in the changelog file

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-sql

I am using the following command to generate the change log

```
liquibase --schemas=test_schema --changelog-file=changelog.xml generateChangeLog
```

My liquibase.properties file is following:

```
url: jdbc:postgresql://xx.xxx.xx.xx:5432/test_db
driver: org.postgresql.Driver
username: testuser
password: test
logFile: liquibase.log
logLevel: debug
defaultSchemaName= test_schema
outputDefaultSchema= true
```

The output in the changelog.xml doesnt have a schemaName, I have multiple schemas in my database so I need schemaname in the changelog as well.

Output :

```
<changeSet author="user1 (generated)" id="xxxxxxxxxxxxx-1">
        <createTable tableName="hello_world">
            <column name="msg" type="CHAR(60)"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
```

Should be test_schema.hello_world or schemaname should be defined. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to append currentSchema= to your db url

e.g.
command line:

```
--url="jdbc:postgresql://DB_HOST:DB_PORT/DB_NAME?currentSchema=SCHEMA_NAME"
```

liquibase.properties

```
url="jdbc:postgresql://DB_HOST:DB_PORT/DB_NAME?currentSchema=SCHEMA_NAME"
```

then call

```
liquibase <other command line params not part of liquibae.properties> generateChangeLog
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes I forgot to update the question, this approach already solved my problem hence upvoting it :)

Answer (score 0):

According to this [doc](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/community/generatechangelog.html), the `--schemas=<name1, name2>` specifies database schemas you want to include. You might want to list out the schemas you want to include. Or you can simply use the `liquibase --changeLogFile=dbchangelog.xml generateChangeLog` command.